# C Are arrays in structs aligned?

Tags: c, alignment

```
struct {
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t bar;
    uint8_t baz;
    uint8_t foos[252];
    uint8_t somethingOrOther;
} A;

struct {
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t bar;
    uint8_t baz;
    uint8_t somethingOrOther;
    uint8_t foos[252];
} B;
```

Does it matter that I've put foos on byte 3 in the first example, vs on byte 4 in B?

Does an array in C have to start aligned?

Is the size of this struct 256 bytes exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the data type is `uint8_t` (equivalent to `unsigned char`), there is no need for padding in the structure, regardless of how it is ordered.  So, you can reasonably assume in this case that every compiler will make that structure into 256 bytes, regardless of the order of the elements.

If there were data elements of different sizes, then you might well get padding added and the size of the structure might vary depending on the order of the elements.

Answer (score 3):

As [the good book](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says (C11 section 6.7.2.1 paragraph 14):

> Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in
>   an implementation- defined manner appropriate to its type...   There
>   may be unnamed padding within a structure object

You didn't "put `foos` on byte 3" - apart from the fact that the first element is always on byte 0, you have no real control over what byte an element will be put on. The compiler can give each field a full machine word or more if it thinks that will provide the most efficient accesses. If so, it will allocate "padding" bytes in between - unused space.

Note that this only applies to structs; arrays themselves do not add any padding bytes (if they did, the pointer arithmetic/indexing rule wouldn't work), so you can be sure that the size of `foos` itself is exactly the declared size, and know the exact alignment of each numbered element.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't matter.

Pretty much every compiler out there will align `struct` fields to a natural boundary appropriate for the target architecture, by inserting hidden "padding bytes" between fields where necessary.

Specifically, since you're using only `uint8_t`, there will be no padding bytes inserted - every field already falls on a naturally-aligned boundary. (Everything is a multiple of one.)

Both of the `struct`s you've shown are exactly 256 bytes in size.  You can confirm this like so:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(struct A)=%zu \n", sizeof(struct A));
    printf("sizeof(struct B)=%zu \n", sizeof(struct B));
}
```

You can prevent this padding from being added by "packing" the structure:

- Microsoft Visual C uses [`#pragma pack(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)
- GCC uses [`__attribute__((packed))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480115/c-are-arrays-in-structs-aligned)

Do note that doing this on a structure with unaligned members can have a serious impact on the performance of your program.

Comment: The second part is what I'm interested in, I'm looking to achieve no padding. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming I made an array of these structs, and that array was also aligned properly, I'm assuming no space would be wasted due to padding?

Comment: @CodySmith: correct.  The basic size of a structure is such that arrays of the structure will be properly aligned too.  Given `struct x { long double d; char c; };` the alignment requirement on `long double` means there'll be padding after the `c` element so that the next element of the array will be properly aligned.

Comment: @CodySmith You can confirm that by using [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) in a test program.