# Does the compiler always place struct at aligned addresses?

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

Let say I have struct:

```
typedef struct my_char {
    char c;
} my_char_t;
```

Can I assume that anytime memory address will be align?

I think maybe yes as in tutorials I see that with structs such as:

```
typedef struct my_char2 {
    char c;
    int i;
} my_char2_t;
```

There is padding between `c` and `i`, so it seems like it assumed `c` is aligned.

Comment: Alignment of structs normally depends on its members. `my_char2` is aligned (as required by `int`) because of the `int` member. That does not imply that `my_char` is aligned. So the short answer is "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any objects created in C by ordinary means (such as by using a declaration that defines an object or by using `malloc` to allocate space) will have the alignment the C implementation requires for that object.

The alignment requirement for `struct my_char { char c; }` is ordinarily just one byte, because the structure contains only a member with a one-byte alignment requirement. The alignment requirement for a structure is typically the strictest alignment requirement of its members, so `struct { char c; }` has a one-byte requirement, and `struct { char c; int i; }` has the same alignment requirement that an `int` has, commonly four bytes in modern C implementations.

Comment: i wonder will it be changed if the question was not char c but char c[16];

Comment: @RDF - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480115/c-are-arrays-in-structs-aligned) may answer your question.

Comment: Some ABIs have higher alignment requirement for struct even if it only contained `char`

Comment: I didn't understand why 'struct { char c; int i; } has the same alignment requirement that an int has', I posted different question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76140503/can-compiler-avoid-padding-in-struct-by-placing-them-in-non-align-address

Answer (score 0):

By little test in onlinegdb.com, you can see that the compiler actually putting this struct in none aligned address in array:

```
my_char_t arr[2];
printf("second struct addr = %p", &arr[1]);
```

And in other struct:

```
typedef struct include_struct {
    char c;
    my_char_t internal_struct;
} include_struct_t;

include_struct_t test;
printf("internal struct addr = %p", &test.internal_struct);
```