# Can compiler avoid padding in struct by placing them in non align address?

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

Let say we have the struct

```
struct {
    char c;
    uint32_t i;
} my_struct_t;
```

from what I see in the web, compilers are padding 3 bytes between the character to the uint32 for alignment.
Can theoretically compiler not pad, but always put the struct in memory address 3mod(4) ?

Comment: I'm doubtful you can easily get a compiler to do that but I'll let the compiler experts answer that one. What you can do to save memory of course, is define a char[5] and memcopy to uint32_t when you want to use it. Then an array of such structs would take 5 bytes per element instead of 8.

Comment: You can tell the compiler to pack the `struct`, which it will do if it doesn't break the alignment rules. In MSVC you can do this with `#pragma pack(push, 1)` before the `struct` definition and `#pragma pack(pop)` after.

Comment: The question is not if I can tell compiler to do it, but if it is legal compiler behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work because it will not work with other features of C, notably arrays and dynamic memory allocation.

Suppose `uint32_t` had an alignment requirement of four bytes and the compiler used no padding in `struct { char c; uint32_t i; } my_struct_t;` and also required it to start at an address that were 3 modulo 4.

Consider what happens when the programmer declares an array of `my_struct_t`, as in `my_struct_t x[5];`. The `x[0]` starts at an address that is 3 modulo 4, and it is 5 bytes long, so `x[1]` starts at an address that is 3+5 = 8 modulo 4, which is congruent to 0 modulo 4. Then the member `x[1].i` is at an address that is 1 modulo 4, so it is misaligned.

Also consider what happens when the programmer dynamically allocates memory for such a structure, as in `my_struct_t *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`. The `malloc` routine is only told how many bytes to allocate. It does not know what they are for. The way this works in current C implementations is that `malloc` always returns memory that is aligned for any ordinary object type (the types listed in C 2018 6.2.8 2). For example, if `double` has an alignment requirement of eight bytes and it is the strictest alignment requirement of any of the ordinary object types, then a `malloc` for that C implementation always returns an address that is a multiple of eight bytes. Since this address is a multiple of eight bytes, it is also a multiple of four bytes and of two bytes and of one byte, so it works for any alignment requirement of ordinary objects. (Some `malloc` routines are designed to return even more strictly aligned memory, for reasons outside the scope of this answer, such as memory that is always a multiple of 16 bytes when the strictest ordinary object alignment requirement is only eight bytes.)

You could change the C language to allow types that can never be in arrays and that could never be dynamically allocated, or you could introduce a new version of `malloc` that was told what alignment to provide, but these changes would complicate the language and have not been found to be useful.